# Can I check a query string in an anchor tag before the anchor tag is clicked on the parent page? If so, how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, query-string

In my application `FirstPage.aspx` I am using a repeater to create a series of links:

```
<a href="MySecondPage.aspx?id=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ValueID")%>">
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ValueName")%></a>
```

Normally, in the page load of `MySecondPage.aspx` I would get the value of the `QueryString` like:

```
string OldID = Request.QueryString["id"];
num SkulloID = Convert.ToInt(SkulloID);

if(SkulloID > 5)
{
  Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Instead of this, what I want to do is somehow on `FirstPage.aspx` get the value of the querystring in the anchor tag to do some logic on just as in the case of `MySecondPage.aspx`. Is something like this possible?

**Edited to test solutions presented**

@CodingBiz I tried the solution you presented and I am having trouble. Here is what I have tried.

In the `Page_Load` i added the following code to set the `CommandArgument` of the link button

```
//Error: The name containder does not exist in the current context
lbnTestLink.CommandArgument = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "ValueID");
```

In the `asp:LinkButton` click command

```
MyID = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, "ValueID");
using (SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmdzero = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [num] FROM [My_Table] Where [ValueID] = @MyID AND [IsSubItem] = 1 AND [FiscalYear] = @FiscalYear", conn2);
    cmdzero.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyID", MyID);
    cmdzero.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FiscalYear", strFiscalYear);
    conn2.Open();
    int countzero = (int)cmdzero.ExecuteScalar();
    int myArgument = countzero;
    if (MyID = myArgument)
    {
        strListLink = "FistPage.aspx";
    }
    else
    {
        strListLink = "SecondPage.aspx?id=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, \"ValueID\")%>";
    }
}
```

I don't understand where the querystring is supposed to get set here.

Comment: Use `<asp:LinkButton />`. You can look that up on the web. Make the CommandArgument the questring id, the onClick or onCommand, check the Id and determine what to do, the redirect to next page, passing the id

Comment: Alternatively you can use Javascript and decide on the client side.